# Is this a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm developing a .NET Framework 4.5 library with C# and Entity Framework 6.1 Code First.

I have these two classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Message> MessagesSent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message> MessagesReceived { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }

    public User Sender { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Recipients { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do to generate Recipient table?

[image]

I'm using Fluent API and I have two classes:

`public class MessageConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Message>`

AND

`public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>`

But I don't what I have to do to generate `Recipient` table.

I'm trying to represent this:

- A message can be sent to one or more recipients.
- A user (recipient) can receive zero or more messages (but he/she could receive a
  message only once).

Is my database design correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class MessageConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Message>
{
    public MessageConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasMany(x => x.Recipients)
            .WithMany(x => x.MessagesReceived)
            .Map(x =>  x.ToTable("MessageRecipients")
                        .MapLeftKey("MessageId")
                        .MapRightKey("UserId"));
    }
}
```

(Please note that I set the table name to `MessageRecipients` instead of `Recipients`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My database design has also support that one message can have only one recipient. I think it does, but you have used `HasMany` and `WithMany`. If I have only one recipient and only one message, does it a problem? I don't think so, but it's my doubt. Thanks.

Comment: If each message has only one recipient, why is `Message.Recipients` a collection?

Comment: Because a message could have one or more recipients. Like a Whatsapp group where you sent a message to a group and every member will receive that message.

Comment: Maybe i don't get you right, but you can't have one-to-many relationship in your Entity and at the same time enforce one-to-one relationship in the Database.